# Google Assistant integration with my custom app?

Tags: android, actions-on-google

I am learning about google actions and made a basic,  google-keep like app which  records notes for logged in users. it has a mobie client and a firebase server. i wish to know if assistant could be made to interact in such a manner that  notes could be created via an assistant session without opening  the mobile client at all.
For example:

```
User (on any screen): "hey google"
AI - "hi , how can i help?"
U - " place a note to call david in customNotter" ( suppose)
Ai - "am sorrry, customnotter  does not exist on your mobile , download it from playstore http"//www.link..." 
U - *downloads customNotter app , installs, logs himself in*
U - " place a note to call david in customNotter"
Ai - "Ok, your note is saved"
*saves note "call david" in customNotter (by somehow calling some code to interact with customNotter's server?)*
```

I can imagine a kotlin code that could be included in my app , which the assistant could trigger which could simply add the note to server, but cannot imagine how assistant could trigger that code with user's auth details and the note data?

---

PS: Also i wish to know if google home could also be integrated for such app. And if not , what are the key factors that would limit google home to not interact with my server ? like suppose am building a complete business model  for CustomNotter , where there is a unified server and many clients like ios / android / web apps . can google home be able to act like another authenticated client, interacting directly with the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option is to use Actions on Google to directly make calls to your Firebase server and update the database that way. The hooks into Android apps are not deep at the moment. [Android Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/) were announced, but are not available right now.

The benefit of doing this is that your Action will work on any Assistant surface, beyond an Android phone, and will not require the user to install your app.

Since you can run [Actions on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/) on [Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/functions-and-firebase), it is easy to incorporate into your Firebase database.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a couple of assumptions here, but before I make different assumptions, I want to clarify something. You said "it has a mobile client and a firebase server". I assume the "firebase server" is what stores the user's notes?

If so, then you don't really need to have the app installed locally at all for the Assistant to work with it. You just need to make sure your mobile app and your Action both have the same user account reference, so they can update and read from the same records in the database. This would work anywhere the Assistant can run Actions - on a mobile device or on a speaker such as Google Home.

In this case, your conversation might look like this:

```
User: Hey Google, ask Custom Notter to remind me to call David.
Assistant: Getting Custom Notter
[Earcon, indicating your Action is running]
Action: Hi there. I've added a note to call David.
[Earcon, indicating the Action is done]
```

This is a very simple example of the conversation. Other conversation flows may also want to indicate if the user hasn't connected such an app to the account, or you may need to prompt them for permission to use their account, etc.

You will need to write server code to handle the processing - all Actions interact with a webhook running on a server in the cloud. You can write this in any language you wish, including Kotlin, and on any service you wish - however Google provides libraries and other support if you run it in node.js using Firebase Cloud Functions or on Google's Cloud.

All the details are available at https://developers.google.com/actions/

If you do have a mobile app, and you want to look into how to get the Assistant to launch things in that app, you can look into [App Actions](https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/), which are coming soon for Android.